# onOptionsItemSelected syntax error

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I'm having problems setting up the responder for the actionbar menu.

I'm using this code and Eclipse keeps telling me "Syntax error on token " . ", delete this token" and
"The method startActiviy(intent) is undefined for the type MainActivity"

This is my code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case.R.Id.about:
            startActivity (new Intent (this, einstellungen.class));
            return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is that a dot after `case`? :)

Comment: startActivity (new Intent (##youractivit.this, einstellungen.class));-- try like that nd check wether it helps and remove the "." after the case

Answer (score 2):

It's this line:

```
case.R.Id.about:
```

it should be:

```
case R.Id.about:
```

Comment: Now he is telling me this: